# Button Not Firing Event Inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

`UIButton`s inside `scrollview` are not firing event. I tried setting `exclusiveTouch delaysTouchesEvent`, but nothing helped.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var categoryArr = ["Jack","Mark","Down","Bill","Steve"]
    var buttonColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor()]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(CGSizeMake(150,scrollView.frame.size.height), buttonCount: 5)
        scrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
        scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
        scrollView.exclusiveTouch = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView  {
        let buttonView = UIView()
        buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)
        let padding = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(padding.width * 0.5, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "showTheNextButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            button.backgroundColor = buttonColors[i]
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
        }
        return buttonView
    }

    func showTheNextButton(sender:UIButton){
        print("ok show the next button")
    }
}

extension TestViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(index)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't any error messages in the console? I had similar problems with unresponsive controls recently and the reason was incorrectly configured constraints.

Comment: nope nothing ....i have scrollview in storyboard..i will post a screenshot of it

Comment: You have already taken UIScrollview in storyboard with IBOutlet connection then what is the purpose of this line? scrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)

Comment: Also I remember when I wanted to create scrolable view I ended up with the solution with another container UIView inside the scroll view and all controlls inside that container view.

Comment: @DmitryKlochkov i am doing the same ...scrollingView is the container view and adding to the scrollview...

Comment: @kb920 scrollingView is the container view to add buttons  and add to the scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the following changes:

```
self.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```

In your `for`-loop, move your `let buttonView = UIView()` to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var categoryArr = ["Jack","Mark","Down","Bill","Steve"]
var buttonColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor()]
let buttonView = UIView()
```

Then subsequently, change the following, again, in your `for`-loop:

Change this line: `buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)` to

```
self.buttonView.frame = self.scrollView.bounds
self.buttonView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

***Addendum:***

Comment this out: `//self.scrollView.exclusiveTouch = true`

I took the liberty of testing it; touches should get registered on the buttons and scrolling should also work horizontally. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

A `UIButton` will not accept touches if it lies outside the bounds of one of its superviews. Make sure all your views are the size and position you expect them to be

Comment: please can you say where i missed it...the whole code is in the question..remained me to bang my head

Comment: @swift BUTCHER try to add visible backgounds to the views to check their boundaries.

Comment: the container view is the problem here...i found out

Comment: Was the container view too small? Did the button lie outside of the container view's bounds?